# Approximating Sine recursively

Tags: python, recursion, series, trigonometry

So I am trying to write a file consisting of two recursive functions. One of which calculates the factorials required for approximating sine via taylor series. The second is another recursive function that will output the value of sine as a float value and will go as far as the amount of terms inputted. Here is a mathematical representation of what I am aiming to get [image]

Here is my code so far (it is unfinished as I am having difficulties with the actual sine computation function):

```
def main():
    ang = int(input("Enter the angle to approximate (in radians): "))
    trms = int(input("Enter the amount of terms to compute: "))
    sinApprox(ang,trms)
def calcFac(x):
    if x <= 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return x * calcFac(x-1)
def sinApprox(angle, terms):
    if calcFac(terms) <= 0:
        return (sinApprox(angle,terms)/calcFac(terms))
    elif terms % 2 == 0:
        return sinApprox(angle**)
```

Note that both functions must be pure and recursive as well.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I need help writing the second function, that will call upon the first function (which calculates the factorial portion of the sine approximation) and will return an approximation of sine as a float value and will continue as many times as the user inputs

Comment: Why does it have to use recursion?

Comment: Well then you get a closure as "Too Broad" instead of "Unclear" if you [edit] your question.

Comment: To get better at understanding how it works and using it in practice @JahKnows

Comment: The base case for sinApprox should be for something like `terms==0`, which has a fixed value, and the recursive case should involve a call to `sinApprox` with `terms-1`, added or subtracted to something you calculate directly for the current `terms`.

Comment: Meanwhile, this really sounds like homework (the “must” bit). It’s fine to ask for help with homework if you read the [help] on how to do it, so if it is, you don’t have to make up a story. Of course if you’re teaching yourself out of a book or something, that’s fine too.

Comment: As a side note, if you find it running intolerably slow for comfortable debugging, I’d look up `@functools.lru_cache` and apply it to your factorial function. (If this is homework, you’ll probably want to remove that before handing it in.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way that this can be done.

```
def calcFac(x):
    if x == 1 or x == 0: return 1
    val = 1
    for i in range(2, x+1):
        val = val * i
    return val

def sinApprox(angle, terms):
    mult = 1
    if terms % 2 == 0: mult = -1

    power = 2*terms - 1
    val = angle ** power
    val = mult * val/calcFac(power)

    if terms == 1: return val
    else: return val + sinApprox(angle, terms - 1)

angle = int(input("Enter the angle to approximate (in radians): "))
terms = int(input("Enter the amount of terms to compute: "))
sinApprox(angle, terms)
```